# Very slow response for Visual Studio 2005 Web Site Administration Tool

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, authentication, permissions

I am working on an ASP.NET application and am trying to add user authentication.  As a first step, I am using the Web Site Administration tool (Website | ASP.NET Configuration) to manage users and permissions.

Accessing this website is incredibly slow.  To load the main page takes 30 seconds.  When navigating to the Security page (also 30 seconds), I am presented with this error:

I have authentication mode set to "Forms" in the web.config file.

---

There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store.

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Unable to connect to SQL Server database.

---

It asks me to run "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regsql.exe", which also gives me an error message.

How do I fix these problems with speed and enabling security/users?

Comment: I have found that website administration tool to be a real pain to use - I wrote a few simple pages to do basic user and group administration myself, based on the examples in the Security Tutorials on the asp.net site (http://www.asp.net/learn/security/)

Answer (score 2):

The issue that you are getting is due to an invalid SQL Server connection, you can setup the SQL Server connection in the web.config, once it is able to actually connect to the database, it will perform in the proper manner.

**EDIT** below is the code needed in web.config to setup the new connection

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="server=yourservername;database=somedatabasename;etc..." />
</connectionStrings>
```